# Should aclocal.m4 go in source control?

Tags: version-control, autoconf

I'm using a couple of macros from the [autoconf archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) in my `configure.ac`. When `aclocal` is run, the macros are placed in `aclocal.m4`. Since this file is automatically generated, I typically wouldn't put it in source control. However, the autogeneration won't work unless the user has the macros installed on their computer in the first place (on Ubuntu I had to do `apt-get install autoconf-archive`). Is it typical practice to include `aclocal.m4` in source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: summary: Do not include `aclocal.m4` in source control.  It is acceptable to include `acinclude.m4`.

No, it is not best practice to do so.  However, it is probably typical practice.  Best practice and common practice often diverge widely when dealing with the autotools.  In my opinion, the expectation is that a developer who is running the autotools is capable of satisfying the dependencies and making the macros available (eg, by installing `autoconf-archive`), so the file should not be included in the version control system.  It is, however, perfectly acceptable to put the macros in `acinclude.m4` and put that file in source control.  When invoked, aclocal will look for definitions in `acinclude.m4` so that the developer running aclocal (and this is the point that seems to throw a lot of projects; there are really only a small handful of people who should ever be invoking the autotools on a project, and everyone else should be building from a release distribution.  If developers working on a project are not modifying the autotool meta-files, there is no reason for them to be running the autotools) does not need to install the autoconf archive.

Comment: Yes but if `configure.ac`, `Makefile.am`, or any of the `*.m4` files are changed, shouldn't `autoreconf && ./configure` be run to update everything?

Comment: Yes, but an extremely small fraction of developers should be modifying the autotool metafiles.  Those people should be capable of installing the macros.  If the macros are included in acinclude.m4, then even that is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I agree that the users shouldn't be running the autotools, but I find it weird that it's not OK to include aclocal.m4, but renaming the exact same file to acinclude.m4 is fine! Anyway I accepted your answer, but will probably just put "install autoconf archive" in the CONTRIBUTING.md instead of including the macros.

Comment: acinclude.m4 and aclocal.m4 serve different purposes.  aclocal.m4 is the output of `aclocal`, and `acinclude.m4` is used as an input for it.